# How to use "extern template" with a nested class which is used by a templated member in the same class?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

First, some context: I'm trying to use the Pimpl idiom in the way Herb Sutter presented it in the solution to his [GotW #101](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_101/). This would look like this in the header file:

```
#include "pimpl_h.h"
class widget {
    class impl;
    pimpl<impl> m;
    // ...
};
```

The implementation would look like this:

```
#include "pimpl_impl.h"
class widget::impl {
    // ...
};
```

The problem I am trying to solve appears when a class using this technique uses another Pimpl class for their own implementation. It includes the "pimpl_impl.h", so the compiler (in my case VC++ 2013) gains knowledge of the concrete template for `pimpl <impl>` of the other class and tries to implicitly instantiate it, which of course results in compilation errors as it does not know about the implementation of that class.

To solve this, I have used the new "extern template" feature of C++ 11 in the header:

```
#include "pimpl_h.h"
class widget {
    class impl;
    pimpl<impl> m;
    // ...
};
extern template pimpl<widget::impl>;
```

This should guarantee that only the explicit instantiation I have in the compilation unit providing the implementation of `widget::impl` leads to an actual instantiation. This compiles without a problem, but IntelliSense shows me an error:

```
Error: 'extern template' cannot follow explicit instantiation of class "pimpl<widget::impl>"
```

As "extern template" cannot be used inside of a class declaration, I cannot write

```
#include "pimpl_h.h"
class widget {
    class impl;
    extern template pimpl<impl>;
    pimpl<impl> m;
    // ...
};
```

and I can't think of any other way. My question is:

Is IntelliSense wrong and the compiler right in accepting my code? Or is it just coincidence that VC++ compiles this and it isn't valid C++?

If my solution is not valid C++, what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out myself. In §14.7.2.11 the standard says

> If an entity is the subject of both an explicit instantiation declaration and an explicit
>   instantiation definition in the same translation unit, the definition shall follow the 
>   declaration.

which is probably what IntelliSense refers to. And this is where I noticed that the error message says "...cannot follow *explicit* instantiation...". There is obviously no explicit instantiation anywhere, just an *implicit* instantiation inside the class definition of `widget`. So I assume that this is a bug inside IntelliSense. Inside the same paragraph, the standard says

> An entity that is the subject of an explicit instantiation declaration and that is also
>   used in a way that would otherwise cause an implicit instantiation (14.7.1) in the
>   translation unit shall be the subject of an explicit instantiation definition some-
>   where in the program; otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

which does not require any specific order of (potential) implicit instantiation and explicit instantiation declaration.

At this point I also realized that my solution is actually overkill for my original problem. I did not want to prevent the implicit instantiation of both the template class *declaration* and *definition* of `pimpl<impl>`, but only the template class *definition* inside `pimpl_impl.h`. The `extern template pimpl<impl>` suppressed both, which solved my problem but does more than necessary. The solution is to declare the actual members of `pimpl<impl>` with `extern template` and explicitly instantiate them later.